# Code in axios().then prevents vuex commit from executing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

Can somebody tell me why a selfdefined date convert method in axios().then prevents vuex commit from commiting.

Here is a code excerpt:

```
  fetchUsers({ commit }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .get("/v1/users")
        .then((response) => {
          for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            response.data[i].created_at = DateConverter(
              response.data[i].created_at
            );
            response.data[i].updated_at = DateConverter(
              response.data[i].updated_at
            );
          }

          commit("FETCH_USERS", response.data);
          resolve(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            alert(error);
            reject(error);
          }
        });
    });
  },
```

The converter util function works because I used it before in each component itself.
But I need the converted date data in my vuex store. If I remove the for loop line
the commit gets executed.

Comment: Mutations should never contain asynchronous operations by design. That should be done in an action instead.

Comment: Ah yea my bad I'm so stupid...

Comment: but wait...this looks like an action (not mutation) so async operation is allowed here

Comment: I'm confused I used async fetchUsers() before and nothing changed anyway

Comment: Michal is right. Did you check your browser network tab/console to ensure that the request is actually not erring out?

Comment: I do get response from my API except that the commit is not executed with the response from my API. If I remove the for loop all works fine.

Comment: Did you check DevTools/console for any error? If the `commit` is not executing and removing `for` loop fixes the problem, the problem is in the loop. But the code looks ok. So the problem might be in the response. Is there `data`? Is it array? Does every entry have a `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in the correct format? Also your `catch` handler is bad. If the condition is not `true`, it just swallows the error so all potential problems hinted above will get unnoticed...

Comment: The response always contains a JSON object with multiple user objects. A user object always contains created_at and updated_at. Basically my API is based on Laravel 8.

Here an excerpt:
[{"id":"XXXX","name":"XXXX","username":"XXXX","email":"XXXX","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2021-05-06T09:28:40.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-05-06T09:28:40.000000Z","deleted_at":null}]

The loop works fine and console.log gives me the converted date values.